# How to Retrieve Objective-c GData Video Description?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, youtube-api

I've been trying to retrieve the description of a youtube video using gdata Objective-c.
I have been able to get the title but how do i get the description?

Title Code:

```
GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The class for YouTube videos in the Objective-C GData library would be GDataEntryYouTubeVideo, not GDataEntryBase.

But the old XML-based GData library is no longer appropriate for use with the YouTube API.  The [newer JSON-based library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) should be used instead.  The description of videos in the JSON API is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource).

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *description=[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup].mediaDescription.stringValue;
```